# CORS PUT/DELETE with custom headers without preflight request

Tags: jquery, http, cors

Is there any ways to do this using jquery without redundant OPTIONS request?

P.S. By the way, what is the great mission of such workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, now it is obviously that OPTIONS can be usefull, but in a bit strange (in my opinion) manner.

All **PUT** and **DELETE** queries, and queries with modified headers are *preflight* with such request.  The great mission is in checking resource availability for providing some kind of operation.

For example, let consider **PUT** operation on http://a.com/users/100500 resource with ABUBAKA header.
Preflight OPTIONS request will contain:

- Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
- Access-Control-Request-Headers: ABUBAKA

using this info you can decide what to do with such an request. For example, such resource could support both PUT and DELETE operations, and using ABUBAKA header is ok. In this case response should at least contain such headers

- Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, DELETE
- Access-Control-Allow-Headers: ABUBAKA

So, OPTIONS is some kind of policy method.